# How to sum the array of object values and assigned them to the relevant key name

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filtering

I need to understand the simplest way of doing this.
I've got an array of objects:

```
const data = [
  {
    group: 'A',
    incomes: {
      "2019-12": 100,
      "2020-12": 200,
      "2021-12": 15
    }
  },
  {
    group: 'B',
    incomes: {
      "2019-12": 25,
      "2020-12": 50,
    }
  }
]
```

What I'm trying to get is simple object where its key is the month from data.incomes and the value is sum of relative month values, so the final result looks like:

```
const totalIncomes = {
  "2019-12": 125,
  "2020-12": 250,
  "2021-12": 15
}
```

Can anybody explain it to me step by step, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solved using reduce and forEach

Inside the reduce function I'm running a `forEach` on the array of keys of the `incomes` object/attribute. For each key which is a date I'm checking if the accumulator of the reduce function contains an attribute for each date and creates if not. After creating the attribute I'm summing the value for the current date attribute.

```js
const data = [{
    group: 'A',
    incomes: {
      "2019-12": 100,
      "2020-12": 200,
      "2021-12": 15
    }
  },
  {
    group: 'B',
    incomes: {
      "2019-12": 25,
      "2020-12": 50,
    }
  }
]

const totalIncomes = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  Object.keys(curr.incomes).forEach((key, index) => {
    if (!acc[key]) {
      acc[key] = 0
    }
    acc[key] += curr.incomes[key]
  })
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(totalIncomes)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried to do almost the same using Object.entries() not Object.keys and that was where I had an error coming from.

Comment: @cmgchess this answer can be improved by adding some useful explanation...

Comment: @Gass i was in a hurry. added some explanation

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not the pretties solutions but you can do it like this, the function is of course not necessary.

```
const data = [
  {
    group: "A",
    incomes: {
      "2019-12": 100,
      "2020-12": 200,
      "2021-12": 15,
    },
  },
  {
    group: "B",
    incomes: {
      "2019-12": 25,
      "2020-12": 50,
    },
  },
];

getterInformation(data);

function getterInformation(object) {
  let objectWithCalculatedValues = {};

  object.forEach((items) => {
    for (const key in items.incomes) {
      if (objectWithCalculatedValues[key] === undefined) {
        objectWithCalculatedValues[key] = 0;
      }

      objectWithCalculatedValues[key] += items.incomes[key];
    }
  });

  console.log(objectWithCalculatedValues);
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's not the prettiest on but it's working and it's also easy for me to understand so it's absolutely fine.
Thank you.

Comment: @Galterius you can improve it easily by reducing the length of your variable names. They should be descriptive but not that much ;)

Comment: I know, sometime I have problem naming vars :))))

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this information may be useful to readers who may be unable to obtain necessary guidance (due to various possible reasons), here is one possible way to achieve the objective (solution):

```
const aggregateIncomesByMonth = () => (
  data.map(d => Object.entries(d.incomes).map(([k, v]) => ({
    key: k,
    value: v
  }))).flat().reduce((fin, itm) => ({
    ...fin,
    [itm.key]: (fin[itm.key] || 0) + itm.value
  }), {})
);
```

**Explanation**

1. Extract only the `incomes` from the `data` array
2. For each `income` object, get the key-value pair and transform into another object of the structure `{key: 20yy-mm, value: nn}`
3. Use `.flat()` to transform the result from step-2 into a 1-dimensional array
4. Use `.reduce` to sum the `value` for those cases where the `key` (ie, 20yy-mm) matches.

**Code-snippet**

```js
const data = [{
    group: 'A',
    incomes: {
      "2019-12": 100,
      "2020-12": 200,
      "2021-12": 15
    }
  },
  {
    group: 'B',
    incomes: {
      "2019-12": 25,
      "2020-12": 50,
    }
  }
];

const aggregateIncomesByMonth = () => (
  data.map(d => Object.entries(d.incomes).map(([k, v]) => ({
    key: k,
    value: v
  }))).flat().reduce((fin, itm) => ({
    ...fin,
    [itm.key]: (fin[itm.key] || 0) + itm.value
  }), {})
);

console.log(aggregateIncomesByMonth());
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach here is to destructure the array. This way I have all the data of the incomes of group A in the variable `A` and the same for `B`.

Then I do a double loop to compare both objects data and see if the dates match. If so, sum  the incomes and add the data to the `total` object.

```js
const data = [
  {
    group: 'A',
    incomes: { "2019-12": 100, "2020-12": 200, "2021-12": 15 }
  },
  {
    group: 'B',
    incomes: { "2019-12": 25, "2020-12": 50 }
  }
]

let A, B, total = {};

[A, B] = [data[0].incomes, data[1].incomes]

for(const date in A){
  for(const d in B){
   total[date] = date === d ? A[date] + B[date] : A[date]
  }  
}

console.log(total)
```